# PDO Insert Query Not Working For Integer

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I have this code to insert a new row into MySQL DB using PDO:

```
$query = INSERT INTO asset_positions (pos_asset_id, pos_latitude, pos_longitude, pos_timestamp) VALUES (:pos_asset_id, :pos_latitude, :pos_longitude, :pos_timestamp)
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$array = [':pos_asset_id' => 1, ':pos_latitude' => -8.5, ':pos_longitude' => 125.5, ':pos_timestamp' => 1398160487];
$statement->execute($array);
echo $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

The query runs without any error shown. The newly inserted row ID is echoed. However, when i look in the DB, it only insert the latitude, longitude and timestamp. The **pos_asset_id** field in the newly inserted row is empty.

Could somebody point out where is the problem? There is no error message displayed. I've been trying to solve this for hours without avail.

Ps. This is my first time using PDO, so please bear with me. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Solved! I didn't notice that there's a FK relation between *asset_positions.pos_asset_id* and *asset.asset_id*. Once i remove this relationship constrains, the INSERT works properly now, the pos_asset_id value is inserted to the record.

Anyway, thanks all! :)

Comment: check field type. PDO has nothing to do here

Comment: @YourCommonSense, Fully agree with you.
Just check your database field type.

Comment: the field type of the pos_asset_id is int(11). I tried changing the field type to varchar(11), but it's still not inserting.

Answer (score 0):

try running with error catching, it will give you better understanding of what is happening.

```
try {
   $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $p) {
    echo $p->getMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But your common sense and user3540050 are right... it's a column related issue probably